# chrome.runtime.registerContentScript not injecting the content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I want to inject content script dynamically from my background script.

The following is the background script

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((event) => {
        chrome.scripting
        .registerContentScripts([
          {
            id: "SCROLL_LISTENER_CONTENT_SCRIPT",
            js: ["content.js"],
            matches: urls,
            runAt:"document_idle"
          },
        ])
        .then(() => {
          console.log("content script registered");
        })
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Error while registering content scripts", error)
        );
    }
  });
});
```

`content.js`

```
function handleScroll() {
    console.log("User scrolled")
    const winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    const scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    console.log(scrolled)
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: "user scrolled"});
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",handleScroll);
```

In the background script the message "content script registered" is being logged.
But when I open a matching url as specified I found no log for "User scrolled".

PS: Although when I am registering this script statically, i.e.. from `manifest.json`. It works

Comment: Assuming `matches` is correct, you probably didn't add `host_permissions` to manifest.json. You can also use optional_host_permissions and ask the user to grant the access explicitly, see the documentation for chrome.permissions API.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But I had resorted to using `executeScript` method, since I found it to be more useful to my use case.